# Re-installing an NServiceBus endpoint stops the service

Tags: nservicebus, psake

When I re-run my psake-based deploy process, my NServiceBus (3.3.0) endpoint does not resume processing messages.  Under services.msc, the Status is blank.

Here's my psake script (with irrelevant stuff removed):

```
function global:deploy_endpoint($name) {

    $project = "$BaseDir\src\$name\$name.csproj"
    $buildPath = "$DeployBaseDir\$name"
    $deployPath = "c:\ReloDotNet2_ServiceEndpoints\$name"

    exec { msbuild $project "/p:Configuration=Debug;OutputPath=$buildPath" "/t:Build" }
    exec { & "$deployPath\NServiceBus.Host.exe" /uninstall }
    exec { msdeploy "-verb:sync" "-source:contentPath=$buildPath" "-dest:contentPath=$deployPath" }
    exec { & "$deployPath\NServiceBus.Host.exe" /install }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The /install does not automatically start the service for you.

You need to start the service after running /install

Comment: John, what makes an Automatic startup automatic actually start then?

Comment: I guess you could use `sc` to start the windows service, eg: sc start  MyEndpoint

Comment: Ifaik there is a bug in the version of TopShelf we're using that prevents the autostart feature to do what it should do.

Comment: automatic startup starts the service automatically when the machine starts up.